# What protocol Firebase ML Kit uses?

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

I plan to use ML Kit with a custom model in my android app and interesting what protocol it uses to download the model from cloud? Is it secure or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML Kit team member here.

It's HTTPS all the way. Custom models are hosted to Google Cloud Storage, and downloaded over HTTPS.